# Filtrar por data no Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela onde é armazenado a data de cadastro no formato DATE(). O cadastro vem desde 2013 e pega todos os dias e meses até dezembro de 2017:

```
2013-01-01
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
......

2017-12-01
2017-12-02
2017-12-03
```

Gostaria de filtrar da seguinte forma:

**Janeiro 2013**

.....
Aqui listasse todos os registros dos dias 01 a 31 de janeiro de 2013
....

e assim por diante até dezembro 2017.

No mysql tentei dessa forma:

```
SELECT MONTH(DataCadastro) AS MesCadastro, YEAR(DataCadastro) AS AnoCadastro FROM `tabela` GROUP BY MesCadastro;
```

Só que ele retorna dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando tento agrupar o ano:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso só da query, pois vou usar o PHP para a listagem.

Answer (score 1):

use um where e o comando between para filtrar entre um intervalo de valores

```
SELECT MONTH(DataCadastro) AS MesCadastro, YEAR(DataCadastro) AS AnoCadastro 

FROM tabela where DataCadastro between '01.01.2013' and '31.01.2013' 

GROUP BY MesCadastro;
```

Comment: Olá Gabriel. Certo, mas como eu aplicaria para a minha solução? Pois estou precisando criar esse filtro para  poder fazer do jeito que mencionei no post.

Comment: SELECT MONTH(DataCadastro) AS MesCadastro, YEAR(DataCadastro) AS AnoCadastro FROM `tabela` where DataCadastro between '01.01.2013' and '31.01.2013' GROUP BY MesCadastro;

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente acredito que não exista uma forma de trazer os resultados como você deseja, mas você pode usar o `group_concat()` para agrupar os meses com um separador e explodir a string no php, que você disse que usará para listagem:

```
SELECT group_concat(MONTH(DataCadastro) separator ',') as MesesCadastro , YEAR(DataCadastro) AS AnoCadastro  FROM tabela where DataCadastro between '01.01.2013' and '31.01.2013' GROUP BY MesCadastro;
```

No php ficaria:

```
$lista[$result['AnoCadastro']] = explode(',', $result['MesesCadastro'] );
//resultado esperado -> $lista['2018'] => [1,2,3...]
```

outra opção é trazer os dados normalmente **sem agrupar** e fazer um loop com php para agrupa-los:

```
$anos = [];
$foreach($result as $res){
   if(!isset($anos[ $res['AnoCadastro'] ])){
       $anos[ $res['AnoCadastro'] ] = [$res['MesCadastro']];
   }else{
       $anos[ $res['AnoCadastro'] ][]= $res['MesCadastro'];
   }
}
```

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat
>   http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php